# Working with a many-to-many realtionship with EF in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an app where I have Recipes and Tags. Since Recipes can have multiple Tags, and Tags can belong to multiple recipes, I have the following models:

```
public class Tag : IModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get;set; }
}

public class Recipe : IModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Title is required.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

My Recipe controller has a an HttpGet Edit action that returns a recipe for the view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {

        Recipe recipe = _recipeService.GetByID(id, "Category,Tags");
        if (recipe == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        CreateEditRecipeViewModel viewModel = new CreateEditRecipeViewModel(recipe, PopulateCategoryLookup(recipe));
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

At this point, the Recipe's Tag collection is populated by my GetById() method. However, I'm unclear about how I am supposed to add a collection to the view model so that it could be surfaced in the View. Here is my current viewmodel:

```
public class CreateEditRecipeViewModel
{        
    [HiddenInput]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Title is required.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I would like to have a textbox where I would have a comma separated list of Tags (e.g. breakfast, vegatarian, gluten-free). When the Edit view is brought up, I would like it populated with the name of each Tag currently assigned to the recipe. When the form is posted, I would like to split the Tag list up, and in the HttpPost Edit action, reconcile the values with EF.

If anyone has guidance on representing a collection of complex objects in a ViewModel and a View, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the [ListBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) tag combined with the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) jquery plugin to do multiselect.  Amazingly straightforward.  I'll make a go at how this should look code wise.  But I don't have VS at hand to test.  Something like:

```
public class CreateEditRecipeViewModel
{        
    [HiddenInput]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<int> TagIds { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Title is required.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

//Then in view...

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TagIds, HelperMethodToGetSelectListOfTags())
```

Then like you mentioned you would just reconcile the selected id's with EF when you turn your view model back into a regular model.

The only drawback to this approach is you would need some separate code for creating new tags.  But you didn't mention that as a requirement.

Hope that helps!